# How to query targeting data from Google AdWords Reporting API?

Tags: google-ads-api

I have create a simple Report in the API that shows how many clicks/impressions were there per targeting combination (e.g. 18-24 male, 18-24 female, etc.). This is very easy to do in the GUI as shown on the picture below.

The problem is I cannot figure out how to do anything like that in the Reporting API. I tried Campaign Performance Report, but it says Age, Gender does not exist as a field and I have not found a field age or gender in the documentation at all.

Is it possible to query this data? Maybe there is some way to "convert" UI report to the AWQL or something like that?

[image]

Comment: I see that the clicks and the impressions are always 0... It is real possible to do that?

Comment: It's a test account, so you cannot actually have real data in there unfortunately...